# How do I make a desktop shortcut in the GNOME fallback UI?

Tags: gnome, edubuntu

How do you make desktop shortcuts on Edubuntu, using the Gnome fallback GUI? I've used Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 before and it's been a no-brainer, but right-clicking on a program through the Applications Menu opens it (same as left-click) with no way I can tell of to make desktop shortcuts.

Comment: Did you make sur right-clik was enabled ?

Comment: Good question, I hadn't considered that was something I needed to enable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you installed GNOME Tweak tool. If not, type

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then, go to the section "Desktop" and enable "Have file manager handle the desktop"